# How to decorate a parent node with background coloured title like a panel style with cytoscape.js

Tags: styles, nodes, panel, parent, cytoscape.js

I'm working with compound graphs library [cytoscape.js](http://js.cytoscape.org/) for some days and familiar with its demo and basic APIs.

But I wonder if it is possible to decorate a parent node with style like the following screenshoot.

[image: expected result]

The defaults style of parent node is just a rectangle frame. Is it possible to render it with a background coloured title ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolve my issue with the following snippet.

```
{
    selector: ':parent',
    style: {
        'background-image': function(){
            return "title.jpg";
        },
        'padding-top' : '25px',
        'background-position-x' : '0',
        'background-position-y' : '0',
        'background-width' : '100%',
        'background-height' : '25px',
        'background-fit' : 'contain',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a background image for the coloured title.

Comment: How to set a background image only for the coloured title ?  `{selector : ':parent', style:{'background-image' : function(){ return 'test.svg'; }}}`  In this way, it was set for the whole parent node not only for title area.

Comment: Just like css, you can position the images.